# Next js: Refetchquery not updating for data fetched in getInitialProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js

I have a component that looks like below

```
class InitialPropsDetail extends React.Component<Props> {

  static getInitialProps = async (ctx: any) => {
    try {
      const { data, error, loading } = await ctx.apolloClient.query({
        query: GET_CURRENT_USER_QUERY,
      })
      const user = data.currentUser
      return { user, errors: error, loading }
    } catch (err) {
      return { errors: err.message }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { user, error } = this.props
    if (error) {
      return (
        <Layout title={`Something went wrong...`}>
          <p>
            <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>Error:</span> {error}
          </p>
        </Layout>
      )
    }

    return (
      <Layout title={`${user ? user.name : ''} | Sav.to`}>
        {user && <UserDetail user={user} />}
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

I want this page to be SSR for SEO reasons. Hence I'm using getInitialProps to render it with some data. Later another action that updates some of this data, and I do a Graphql refetchQuery on that action. The query is being fired and that data is returned. However, the view doesn't update with the new data. I tried the same in another view without `getInitialProps` and it works fine.

How do I update the data that is fetched via `getInitialProps` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> `getInitialProps` enables server-side rendering in a page and allows you to do **initial data population**, it means sending the page with the data already populated from the server... For the initial page load, `getInitialProps` will run on the server only. `getInitialProps` will then run on the client when navigating to a different route via the `next/link` component or by using `next/router`.

Just like its name implies, `getInitialProps` is only ran once when your page is loaded. Generally, you should avoid using ApolloClient like this -- instead, you should configure it as shown in [the official examples](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo). This way, you can use the `useQuery` hook like normal instead of using `getInitialProps`. When the page is rendered on the server, you'll use `getDataFromTree` to hydrate your cache based on any `useQuery` hooks that are rendered.

Comment: So ideally there is no need to use `getInitialProps` at all? I was also looking at options to fetch data on server using hooks! Thanks for the mention. 
One more question - by hydrating the cache, you mean the graphql cache?

Comment: The code still uses `getInitialProps` to do what I described. Check out the example and the Apollo docs [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/server-side-rendering/).

Comment: Got it! What if I'm already using something like `next-with-apollo`? Would that be a duplicate? Don't mind if the questions are stupid. This is my first time around Next js and SSR.

Comment: Same thing. That HOC just takes care of all the boilerplate in the example. You just use hooks like normal with it.

Comment: If I don't use `getInitialProps` though, would the page be SSR?

Comment: You're still using `getInitialProps` because the HOC uses them. But your site would be SSR regardless of whether you used it.

Comment: Just noted that when I'm not using `getInitialProps` and hooks directly - and view the source what rendered is the loading state of the page and not the actual content itself :/